# Cant get onUploadProgress at promise chain?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have a multiple posts that require a for loop and i want show to the user a progress bar. When there is a single post its works fine and i can see the upload progress, but if i try multiple post with for loop cant access to onUploadProgress event, even console.log(progressEvent) returns nothing. I am using nuxt framework.

```
  async post() {
  this.upload.open = true;
  let promises = [];
  let tuc = this.slider_items;
  const len = tuc.length;
  this.upload.queue = len;   //total post count

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    let formData = new FormData();
    /*
     *  ...
     */
    formData.append("cover", cover);
    formData.append("_method", "PUT");

    promises.push(
      this.$axios
        .$post(`/api/admin/slides/${i + 1}`, formData, config)
        .then((res) => this.upload.curr_queue++) //which post right now
        .catch((err) => {
          if (!err) {
            return;
          }

          const { errors } = err.response.data;
          this.upload.err.push(err);
          this.upload.err_res.push(Object.values(errors));
        })
    );
  }

  const config = {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },

    onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
      this.upload.percentage = parseInt(
        Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
      ); /// this is loading screen's progress bar, showing upload percentage

      console.log(progressEvent);  /// Cant see that
    },
  };

  await Promise.all(promises).then((res) =>
    console.log("promises : " + res)
  );
},
```

What i am trying to do, there is a single progress bar and i want to show upload progress percentage in order of posts, and when a post successful this will increase upload.curr_queue and upload progress's percentage will be restart with new post.

If you guys want to look full post code i can edit this section. Basically i cant understand why i cant access to onUploadProgress event.

Comment: its better to declare your `config` at the top instead of under the axios function. usually u should get an error `Cannot access 'config' before initialization`

Comment: @Ifaruki thank you so much. i wasted my 2 days on this problem and used every source for help but you're the first person who tried to help and its works! thank you so much sir! all i was need to carrying config to top...

Comment: next time press F12 and check your console for errors

Comment: well I did but there was no error, I think this problem derived by promise.all usage